# How can I loop through Items in the Item Template from an asp:Repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater, which is bound on preRender with items. In the Item template each row has a check box. This works fine.

I'm trying to loop through all the checkboxes in the item template after it has been bound. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: There are plenty of life-cycle events on the Repeater you could tap into, including events that occur as each item is being created and/or bound, you don't have to wait until the end, and you can discover these events for yourself directly in the IDE. What is it you need to do with these checkboxes?

Comment: Why are you binding the Repeater on preRender? This is very late, normally you would do this in Page_Load stage. If you want to loop all rows of repeater only on databinding, repeaters [ItemDataBound-Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) would be a good place, because that wouldn't cause an extra-loop-

Comment: On a postback or client side. Either is possible, but preference is very important to get a proper answer you can use.

Comment: @Tim, a use-case for binding during PreRender is that you may be responding to one or more other events. Load isn't appropriate in such a scenario, and indeed the other event handlers may not be sufficient.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to use the ItemDataBound event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx

You will want to check the ItemType of the RepeaterItem so that you don't attempt to find the checkbox in Header/Footer/Seperator/Pager/Edit

Your event would look something along the lines of:

```
void rptItems_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var checkBox = (CheckBox) e.Item.FindControl("ckbActive");

        //Do something with your checkbox...
        checkBox.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

This event can be raised by adding the event in your code behind like so:

```
rptItems.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(rptItems_ItemDataBound);
```

Or by adding it to the control on the client:

```
onitemdatabound="rptItems_ItemDataBound"
```

---

Alternatively you can do as the others suggested and iterate over the RepeaterItems, however you still need to check the itemtype.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptItems.Items)
{
    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var checkBox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("ckbActive");

        //Do something with your checkbox...
        checkBox.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

You would want to do that in the **Page PreRender**, after the Repeater has been bound.

Comment: I vote +1 for **check the itemtype** in the iterating approach

Answer (score 21):

Try this.

```
for each (RepeaterItem ri in Repeater1.Items)
{
     CheckBox CheckBoxInRepeater = ri.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;

    //do something with the checkbox
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int item = 0; item < Repeater.Items.Count; item++)
{
   CheckBox box = Repeater.Items[item].FindControl("CheckBoxID") as CheckBox;
   if (box.Checked)
   {
      DoStuff();
   }
   else
   {
      DoOtherStuff();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few different thoughts come to mind:

1. Is there a specific need to bind this repeater in preRender? Consider using the more typical way of binding after Page_Load event.
2. Why are you wanting to look for the checkboxes after the repeater has been bound? Can you do whatever you need to do *while* it is being bound by using this event:

   ```
   OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_OnItemDataBound"
   ```
3. Either way, you can always go back and look inside the repeater by just iterating through it. Note that you might have to do a recursive search if the checkbox is nested in a different element inside the repeater item

   ```
   for each (RepeaterItem r in Repeater1.Items) {
       CheckBox c = r.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;
       //DO whatever
   }
   ```