# How do I access every item in a repeater that is not the one being select?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Sorted. I've added the following in Page_Load. So simple

```
For Each thingy As RepeaterItem In uxMaterialNeedsRepeater.Items
    Dim uxRepeaterItemPanel As Panel = CType(thingy.FindControl("uxRepeaterItemPanel"), Panel)
    uxRepeaterItemPanel.BackColor = Nothing
Next
```

I Have a repeater

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="uxMaterialNeedsRepeater">

    <ItemTemplate>

            <p>

                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="uxRepeaterItemPanel">

                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="uxMaterialNeedLinkButton" CssClass="Label" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>'>Select</asp:LinkButton>

                    <%#ReturnListOfMaterials(Container.DataItem)%>

                </asp:Panel>

            </p>

    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

and when a user clicks the LinkButton generating an ItemCommand I highlight the 'row' the user has selected

```
Protected Sub uxMaterialNeedsRepeater_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles uxMaterialNeedsRepeater.ItemCommand

    If e.CommandName = "Select" Then

        '   Highlight the selected row
        Dim uxRepeaterItemPanel As Panel = CType(e.Item.FindControl("uxRepeaterItemPanel"), Panel)
        uxRepeaterItemPanel.BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightGreen

    End If

End Sub
```

but if they select another row then I have two rows highlighted (highlit?) and I want to un-highlight the original row. So my thinking is to auto un-highlight all rows first.

How do I do this?

I've tried a few things including setting it at the ItemCreated event but that doesn't work either.

```
Protected Sub uxMaterialNeedsRepeater_ItemCreated(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles uxMaterialNeedsRepeater.ItemCreated

    '   Remove any highlighting from all rows
    Dim uxRepeaterItemPanel As Panel = CType(e.Item.FindControl("uxRepeaterItemPanel"), Panel)
    uxRepeaterItemPanel.BackColor = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281559/asp-net-repeater-loop-through-items-in-the-item-template

Comment: Well that gets me one step closer. What I need to do is this: `For Each thingy As RepeaterItem In uxMaterialNeedsRepeater.Items
            Dim uxRepeaterItemPanel As Panel = CType(e.Item.FindControl("uxRepeaterItemPanel"), Panel)
            uxRepeaterItemPanel.BackColor = Nothing
        Next`

But I can't work out what event I can put that it.

Comment: Is this question resolved? If it is, you can post your solution as an answer so that other people can benefit from your experience.

Comment: Cheers @ShaiCohen I didn't realise I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually a very simple fix.

I looped through the repeater items on page load and reset the back colour of every panel control first.

```
For Each thingy As RepeaterItem In uxMaterialNeedsRepeater.Items
    Dim uxRepeaterItemPanel As Panel = CType(thingy.FindControl("uxRepeaterItemPanel"), Panel)
    uxRepeaterItemPanel.BackColor = Nothing
Next
```